# Get data from country and state tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables, promoSchedule

```
id | startdate | enddate  
1 |1 july | 10 july  
2 |1 july | 20 july  
3 |2 july | 30 july  
4 |1 july |15 aug
```

and 3 more tables, promoScheduleCountry, promoScheduleState and promoScheduleCity. Data in these tables is,

```
promoScheduleCountry  
id | promoScheduleId | countryId  
1  | 1               | US

promoScheduleStates  

id | promoScheduleId | stateId  
1  | 2               | New york 



promoScheduleCities  
id | promoScheduleId | cityId  
1  | 3               | Amsterdam  
2  | 4               | Geneva
```

country, state and city are releted.

Now **I** want all the promoScheduleIds where if **I** provide countryId say US, then from 3 tables i.e promoScheduleCountry, promoScheduleState and promoScheduleCity, I want promoScheduleIds 1,2,3,4.

If I promovide stateId say new york, then from 2 tables i.e promoScheduleState and promoScheudleCity, I want  promoScheduleIds 2,3,4.

I want the query or store procedure for this or guideline how to do that?
For understanding purpose i haven the names of country,state and city. Actually there are 3 more tables country, state and city. and they are related with each othe i.e in state table there is primary key of country and in city tables there is primary key of state table

Comment: What is the relation between `promoScheduleCountry`, `promoScheduleState` and `promoScheduleCity` ?

Comment: You must have some relationship between those tables or you must another table which defines which city belong to which state & which state belong to which country. Poor DB design.

Comment: IF there is relationship between these three table then and then you can get proper output of your query or store procedure.

Comment: @ITppl there is relationship between city, state and country tables. Actually 3 more tables country,state and city and there ids are used in promoScheduleCountry, promoSState and promoSCity tables.

Comment: @TejasVaishnav 3 more tables country, state and city, and they are releated with each other, and there ids are used in promoScheduleCountry,promoSState and promoSCity tables

Comment: @ITppl for understanding purpose i have given the names, actually there are ids

Comment: @Vishal Redesign your table mate

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but more a query about the design of your tables, which seems a little bit unneccessarily complex (as you are finding when you go to query it).

You could replace your three promoXXX tables with one PromoLocations table:

```
ID    PromoScheduleID   CountryID   StateID   CityID
```

This would probably make your code considerably easier to code and query.

Answer (score 0):

you should redesign your table like following

```
CountryTable    : CountryID (int, autonumber, PK), CountryName (varchar2)
StateTable      : StateID (int, auto number, PK), StateName (varchar2), ContryID (int , FK)
CityTable       : CityID (int, auto number, PK), CityName (varchar2), StateID (int, FK)
```

rather than using this three promoScheduleCountry,  promoScheduleStates, promoScheduleCities tables, create new one like this

```
PromoLocation   : PromoLocationId (int, autonumber, PK), PromoScheduleID (int, FK), CountryID(int, FK), StateID(int, FK), CityID(int, FK)
```

Dummy data in all tables would be like

```
CountryTable
---------------------------
CountryID   |   CountryName
---------------------------
1           |   USA
2           |   France
3           |   Russia
4           |   India
---------------------------

StateTable
-----------------------------------------
StateID     |   StateName   |   CountryID
-----------------------------------------
1           |   New York    |   1
2           |   Alaska      |   1
3           |   Michigan    |   1
-----------------------------------------

CityTable
-----------------------------------------
CityID      |   CityName    |   StateID
-----------------------------------------
1           |   Albany      |   1
2           |   Buffalo     |   1
3           |   Rochester   |   1
-----------------------------------------

PromoSchedule
-----------------------------------------
promoScheduleid     |   PromoEventName  
-----------------------------------------
1                   |   Event1          
2                   |   Event2
3                   |   Event3  
4                   |   Event4
----------------------------------------

PromoLocation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PromoLocationID     |   PromoScheduleID     |   CountryID   |   StateID     |   CityID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   |   1                   |   1           |               |
2                   |   2                   |               |   1           |
3                   |   3                   |               |               |   1   
4                   |   4                   |               |               |   2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

your query would be like

```
SELECT * FROM PromoSchedule WHERE promoScheduleid IN
(SELECT promoScheduleid FROM PromoLocation WHERE CountryID = '<CountryID>' OR 
        StateID IN (SELECT StateID FROM StateTable WHERE CountryID = '<CountryID>') OR
        CityID IN (SELECT * FROM StateTable WHERE StateID IN (SELECT StateID FROM StateTable WHERE CountryID = '<CountryID>')))
```

This can be accomplished using JOIN too.

Comment: actually to insert all the data in promoLocation table it will be very difficult to maintain. the relationship between country , state and city is exactly same as in my tables and its ids are used in promoScheduleCountry, promoScheduleState and promoScheduleCity tables.

Comment: if i have to use promoScheduleCountry, promoScheduleState and promoScheduleCity table how will be query is

Comment: than you can use temporary table, Get promoScheduleId from all three tables and store it in temp table and than fetch the results using promoScheduleId of temp table